# drop a foreign table in tera data show me a weird message. I can't drop it

Tags: teradata

what is going on ?
I want to drop a foreign table (NOS) in tera data.
It shows me a weird message.
show case below :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDkZm.jpg

Comment: Studio is probably logging on one session per query tab and the number of sessions for the user's profile is reached. Close some tabs or disconnet them

Comment: You are right.   answer me,  select your answer  as  the correct answer.